# How can I create push messages without using signalr and without pulling?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, push

I'm building a chat application without signalR (project specifications), 
how can I create "push messages" - without using a signalR and without pulling all the time.

Now the project runs with *`pulling ajax - requests`* I do not want to create multiple requests to db and server without need.

**Edit**:
I do not want to use Sockets is it possible to do without any HTML5 features?
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`HTML5 WebSockets`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/). You will have to implement a server that respects [`the protocol`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) and access it from the client. It's gonna be quite a lot of work that other people have already done and bundled for you under the form of a ready to use product: SignalR.

Comment: Sorry edited my question... I have written my project specifications.

Comment: Sorry, no, that's not possible. Without HTML5 specific features you are doomed to use long polling or AJAX requests at regular intervals. That's the reason why people invented WebSockets.

Comment: :) I know that was my exact words.

Comment: Well then the answer is : this is not possible. Sorry I didn't read your exact requirements.